# Ubuntu 16.04 hangs on shutdown with hard LOCKUP

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, reboot

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 (with encrypted partition) on a Dell Inspiron 5567 a month ago. Now after some usage Ubuntu hangs while shutting down. In ca. 90% of the cases it just freezes in the plymouth screen and I have to power off via hard reset with the power button.

Things I have tried so far:

- Shutdown via `sudo swapoff -a && systemctl poweroff`. Does not change anything. Makes sense since there is no swap partition configured.
- Get some information via debug shell, running `systemctl start debug-shell` before powering off. But I cannot switch with <kbd>Strg</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to the debug shell, since the laptop freezes and doesn't respond to any keyboard input (also not to <kbd>Strg</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>).
- Editing the grub file `/etc/default/grub`. I set `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"`, but that changed nothing. For further debugging I changed it to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""` to see some debugging output.
- I wanted to disable USB 3.0 settings in the BIOS, but there are no settings like this in the Dell BIOS (or I didn't find them).
- `sudo apt-get clean`
- Adding `DefaultTimeoutStartSec=30s` and `DefaultTimeoutStopSec=10s` to `/etc/systemd/system.conf`.
- I have looked in the logfile `/var/log/syslog` for information but have not seen any unusual entries.

When I shut down the system I see lots of green [OK] messages until it finally reaches `Reached target shutdown`. Then after a while a call trace appears ending with `Fixing recursive fault but reboot is needed!`. Again after some seconds a message appears saying `NMI watchdog: Watchdog detected hard LOCKUP on cpu 0`:
[image: first error]
And at least there is another call trace and the system freezes:
[image: freeze screen]

Any suggestions how to fix this issue without reinstalling the complete laptop? Or any suggestions how to get more debugging output?